# jQuery: Does 'visible' detect elements that are initially hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML markup like this:

```
<div class="item first">First Item</div>
<div class="item second">Second Item</div>
<div class="item third">Third Item</div>
<div class="item fourth">Fourth Item</div>      
<div class="item fifth">Fifth Item</div>
<div class="item sixth">Sixth Item</div>
<div class="item seventh" style="display: none;">Seventh Item</div>
<div class="item eighth" style="display: none;">Eighth Item</div></div>

<div class="button"></div>
```

You'll notice that the first 6 classes are visible, but the last 2 classes have the display: none style.

That's because I'm letting the user swap out two items for two other items, should they choose to do so. Below is very simplified pseudo-code, but I'm not worried about it because it works -- I just wanted to give you an idea of what's going on:

```
$('.item').click(function(){  
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + thisClass).fadeOut();
    $('.seventh').fadeIn();
});
```

Now we're getting to the real problem:

I always have six visible items on the page (some that started out hidden, and some that started out visible). I've been doing something like this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('#id').find('.class:visible').each(function() {
        //do something
    })
});
```

However, the 'each' never finds the divs that were hidden on pageload, even though they may be visible by the time the button click event takes place.

I can verify this with a counter. Let's say I unhid two divs and hid two divs. I have a total of six visible divs, so I'd expect to get six results -- but the counter never goes higher than four in that particular case, and it never returns to me the classes of the originally hidden divs.

Any thoughts on what I could do differently?

tldr; `$('#id').find('.class:visible')` is only finding divs that were visible on pageload, and ignoring divs that were once hidden but are now visible.

Comment: Since the dom search doesn't occur until the button click there is no reason they shouldn't be found unless the class was removed or elements were moved. Symptoms described don't make sense based on information shown...going to need a demo that replicates problem

Comment: _"However, it never 'sees' the divs that were hidden on pageload, even though they may be visible by the time the button click event takes place"_ ? Not certain interpret Question correctly ? If elements are visible when button click takes place , why would elements be returned as hidden elements ?

Comment: Just a matter of discussion - `var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.' + thisClass).fadeOut();` instead of this couldn't be it just `$(this).fadeOut()`?

Comment: the `$('.item').click` code should fail. `thisClass` won;t create valid selector due to multiple classes on elemnts and `$('.item-seventh')` doesn't exist in code shown.

Comment: @charlietfl -- Sorry about that, I simplified it so I didn't have to post a ton of code.  In reality, each class is item-[unique-id]. I just trim off the item- bit to get the value I need.

Comment: @Duplosion I figured was something like that or you would have had issues with it. Just part of the puzzle on our end though when try to sort issues out

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is to show 6 items all the time, but also to allow user to remove 2 existing items for the 2 hidden items if so

```js
var counter = 0;
$('.item').one('click.limit', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
  $('.item:hidden:first').fadeIn();
  if (++counter == 2) {
    $('.item').off('click.limit')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="item first">First Item</div>
  <div class="item second">Second Item</div>
  <div class="item third">Third Item</div>
  <div class="item fourth">Fourth Item</div>
  <div class="item fifth">Fifth Item</div>
  <div class="item sixth">Sixth Item</div>
  <div class="item seventh" style="display: none;">Seventh Item</div>
  <div class="item eighth" style="display: none;">Eighth Item</div>
</div>
<div class="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is....

I'm an idiot. On the initially hidden divs, there was a space in the class name that I didn't notice.

*sigh*

Thanks for your help though, everyone.